# How to use this Android Week View Library

Tags: android, kotlin, calendar

I'm trying to implement on my android application a calendar week view where I will show all the events in that week like a school schedule.
After searching for a while I found this library that seems to work:
https://github.com/thellmund/Android-Week-View/wiki
but I can't understand how I can add events on it.

This is the sample code that it's on their github:

```
data class MyEvent(
  val id: Long,
  val title: String, 
  val startTime: Calendar, 
  val endTime: Calendar
)

class BasicViewModel : ViewModel() {
  private val _events = MutableLiveData<List<MyEvent>>()
  val events: LiveData<List<MyEvent>> = _events
  
  // ...
}

class BasicActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  private val viewModel by viewModels<BasicViewModel>()
  
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_basic)
    
    val adapter = MyCustomPagingAdapter<Event>()
    weekView.adapter = adapter
    
    viewModel.events.observe(this) { events ->
      adapter.submitList(events)
    }
  }
}
```

What should I do to add an event on it?
Thanks for your help

Comment: That seems like it is handled by your adapter. See https://github.com/thellmund/Android-Week-View/wiki#simple-adapter and https://github.com/thellmund/Android-Week-View/wiki#paging-adapter in the documentation that you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

clone this [repo](https://github.com/thellmund/Android-Week-View) in your android studio and then run the sample app to see the various implementations of `WeekView`

1. Basic - Asynchronous events fetching
2. Static Week - Static week without horizontal scrolling
3. Limited Date and Time Range - Shows only the current month (Limits days from 8AM to 8PM)
4. Custom Font - Custom font in `WeekView` (All-day events arranged horizontally)
5. With `Fragment` - Displays `WeekView`  within a `Fragment`

[image]